# LockBox 3 - Components not working with VCL in Delphi XE8

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-xe8, lockbox-3

I have just downloaded and installed LockBox 3 in my Delphi XE8.
But: The VCL Tool-Palette does not show the components.
When I switch to a Firemonkey form I can see both, the VCL and Firemonkey Groups. In a VCL form I can see neither.

After: Restarting Delphi. Only installing the VCL-version. Restarting Delphi. Opening a VCL form. Installing the Firemonkey-version.
I can see the Group now, but I can not place anything on a VCL-Formular.
I get an exception when dragging a LockBox-component to my formular:

"Klasse TLbMD5 kann bei diesem Modul nicht angewendet werden"

"class TLbMD5 can not be used in this module"

My question is: How do I get the components to work with the VCL?

Comment: Did you go back to the VCL form designer after seeing them for FMX? By default, immediately after installing any components, you cannot see them until you open an actual form. The moment you open any form (or data module for that matter), the tool palette refreshes.

Comment: I have already restarted and reinstalled the components, to no avail. - Just now I installed the Firemonkey package - and now I can see the VCL ones. THAT is strange.

Comment: What I don't understand is why an encryption has designtime components.

Comment: @DavidHefferman   I thought that's to allow you to set properties through the Object Inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Where have you downloaded the LockBox 3 components from?

If you have downloaded them from SourceForge then you are not using latest version.

I strongly suggest downloading them from GitHub

https://github.com/TurboPack/LockBox3

As far as I know all components that previously formed TurboPack are now being maintained on GitHub and no longer on SourceForge.